# Where do I find Androidmanifest.xml on my device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to modify the `Androidmanifest.xml` for the browser on my device so that I can execute an app by loading a `URI` in the browser.

I've been running around the file system in `ADB SHELL` all day, but can't seem to find it. Plus there is no `FIND`, nor `LOCATE` command on the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can theoretically find the Androidmanifest.xml file in the APK.

Every APK contains the compiled source code of the application. There is no useable decompiler for APKs at the moment so it is not possible to change the content of one.

In addition to the compiled code and the other resources of the application, an APK also contains a signature from the developer, which will become invalid when the content is changed to verify the source of an APK. An Android system won't install an APK with an invalid signature, so even if you could change the content of the APK, you still couldn't use it.

The conclusion: You cannot do what you are trying to do.

Comment: If he resigned the modified apk after making the changes to the apk wouldn't it be possible to install the app? The android build system did support some directives for including PREBUILT_APKS if you are building custom roms. In the case of modifying an app to run on your own device it should be possible to get the new apk installed. The AOSP build systen lets you specify a certificate to use to resign or sign apps being built.

Comment: You can get it through reverse-engineering tools like [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). Also, as @QuentinSwain said it is possible to resign APKs (but you need to reinstall it, updating is not possible).

Comment: Resigning an APK without entirely recompiling your OS from scratch with the AOSP source only works if you recompile the APK. Recompiling the APK only works if you have the source code. apktool is very unpractical for larger APKs at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio on Windows 10/11, it’s in: app/src/main.

Comment: Read the question; the OP wants to change the manifest of a published, installed app by someone else (the browser).