# Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE with Error: Package has not requested permission android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE

Tags: java, android, service, permissions, adb

### Context

While trying to launch a tor service in Orbot, on a rooted phone, I am encountering some difficulties.

When I try to launch the tor connection with:

```
adb shell am startservice -n org.torproject.android/.service.OrbotService
```

I get error:

```
Starting service: Intent { cmp=org.torproject.android/.service.OrbotService }
Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE
```

Yet when I try to set that permission with:

```
adb shell pm grant org.torproject.android android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE
```

It throws error:

```
Security exception: Package org.torproject.android has not requested permission android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE

java.lang.SecurityException: Package org.torproject.android has not requested permission android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.BasePermission.enforceDeclaredUsedAndRuntimeOrDevelopment(BasePermission.java:444)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:2238)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.access$1100(PermissionManagerService.java:122)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService$PermissionManagerServiceInternalImpl.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:3239)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PackageManagerService.java:5788)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1955)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:230)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21952)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4876)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4049)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767385/7437143) I should create the request in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the Orbot `.apk` file, however, I am not compiling the apk, the apk is already pre-installed from a store, and I would expect the request for the permission to be stored when I try to launch the service. (Such that it recongises the previous request for permmission when I try to set it).

### Question

How can I start the service and set the required permission successfully using `adb`?

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386719/150978)? I assume it is the same case here, the service does not make use of the permission, instead it defines that the component using the service requires it.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed seems related to this error, however, I did not yet understand it well enough to apply that knowledge to start the service with the required permission.